# ¿Cómo hacer un .bat que haga ping con fecha y hora?

Tags: batch, ping

Hice el código para que me haga un `ping` infinito, pero necesito hacer que registre fecha y hora, ¿alguien podría ayudarme? Gracias.

Comment: Estimado, por favor comparte tu código para poder ayudarte de una forma mas clara. Lee [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que puedas guiarte.

Comment: Seria bueno ver tu codigo, para poder ayudarte de mejor forma, caso contrario tu pregunta seria cerrada

Answer (score 1):

De esta manera podes tener un bucle infinito y mostras la fecha y el status del ping en powershell.

```
while($True){
$Tsc = Test-Connection nombredelservidor -count 1 -quiet
if ($Tsc){
    #Escribe la fecha y "Ping ok" en un archivo
    write-host (get-date),"Ping ok" | Out-File c:\carpeta\archivo_OK.txt
}
else{
    write-host (get-date),"Fallo" | Out-File c:\carpeta\archivo_Fallo.txt
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Con PowerShell, puede hacer este:

```
for ($i=0; $i -le 10; $i++) {Test-Connection nombredelservidor -count 1 -quiet ; get-date ; start-sleep 1}
```

Resultados:

```
True
Tuesday, December 17, 2019 1:52:23 PM
True
Tuesday, December 17, 2019 1:52:24 PM
```